# Reference for canonical quantization of E.M field (for quantum optics purposes in the end)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian-formalism

I am looking for a nice book or online course treating in a rigorous way the quantization of the E.M field.

My needs in the end are to do quantum optics, but I would like to see the proof in a nice way. Indeed in the books I have read, they basically show that the Hamiltonian is a sum of harmonic oscillators, and then quantize each mode.

But I am more interested in a rigorous derivation with the Lagrangian, using the canonical quantization.

Where can I find such resource ?

Comment: This can be found in any QFT textbook.

Comment: In QFT they do it with relativistic particles which give some extra complexification

Comment: Actually it is treated in "Photons and Atoms: Introduction to Quantum Electrodynamics" by Cohen Tanoudji